# How to execute exe of different machine from my machine in node.js

Tags: node.js, electron

We are building an application in node js with electron. There is another software which is installed in all other machines.Now  in my node js application i want to launch those software on there respective machines.Is it Possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this via commands and a child process via spawn.
See [▶NodeJs API Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

#### On Windows

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'my.bat']);

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

#### Linux

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, if i execute above code from my local machine can it execute exe on remote machine to?

Comment: I did research and found that we can use npm like "node-cmd" or "node-powershell" and execute command prompt/power shell commands to execute exe on remote computers

Comment: You can execute it on remote machines if you write a client/service that is installed on those machines. You will also need a master programm which emits the commands to all or individual computers.

Comment: Also node-cmd is a nice wrapper for the functions i wrote you. I would suggest you to use such packages if you want to get things done quick. But keep in mind you'll make yourselfe dependent on any package you add which you should overthink if you aim for bigger programms. Good luck and happpy coding 

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked as charm for me.

```
var cmd = require('node-cmd');
cmd.get('WMIC /node:"ABC-XXXXXXX" process call create "C:\\Setup\\app7.exe"',function(err, data, stderr){
    console.log('err:', err)
    console.log('stderr:', stderr)
})
```

Remote machine name : ABC-XXXXXXX

Path of exe on remote machine: C:\Setup\app7.exe